# How do I tie in jQuery code onto certain pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, performance

I have a Wordpress based site (which I think is irrelevent to this question, but I'm putting it out there in case it impacts the answers).

And I want to keep javascript out of the page/post content. I'm introducing some jQuery functionality for form validation on a few different pages, and I'm trying to keep my javascript together in one file.

The theme I'm using lets me tick off a checkbox to include jQuery, and then I have a footer script block which pulls in my custom javascript for the site.

When the page is ready, I want to run the javascript to customize each of the special pages with their code using jQuery to hook up the event/validation code.

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    el = $('#myhelpform'); 
    if (el.length > 0)
    {  
        myhelpform(el);
    }

    el = $('#pkform');
    if (el.length > 0)
    {
        pkform(el);
    }

    el = $('.buynowreceipt')
    if (el.length > 0)
    {
        ...
    }      
});  // ready
```

...keeping the specific functionality in different functions, but I'm wondering if this is the way to go. I'm a javascript/jQuery noob.

Is my example above the best/only way to do this and if not, how would you solve the problem?

**UPDATE: To clarify my question a bit**

This is not question about how to load scripts conditional on certain pages. It's about having a single js file that gets downloaded once, is in the cache, but not has to run certain page specific stuff based on the body class of the page or the existence of a form on a page, or something else.

For example, I recently learned an alternative to my code above would be to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    el = $('#myhelpform'); 
    if (el.length > 0)
    {  
        myhelpform(el);
    }
});


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    el = $('#pkform');
    if (el.length > 0)
    {
        pkform(el);
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    el = $('.buynowreceipt')
    if (el.length > 0)
    {
        ...
    }      
});
```

I'm just trying to learn how to do it right the first time.

And **Thank You** to Obmerk for having explained conditionally *loading* scripts in Wordpress the correct way.

Comment: I don't think it's ideal because you're loading a larger JS file than necessary for each page. If you're going to go down this route though, I would break the if conditions up into different functions instead and use a `switch` statement

Comment: It is very relevant that you are using wordpress, because wordpress have built in functions to help with such a filtering . see my answer .

Comment: I would also be cautious loading scripts via the dashboard of a theme; always better practice to hardcode it in there.

Comment: @1977 +1 on the caution to load scripts via themes ( 99% of the cases , they will deregister the original wp ones, or load from a CDN ( BAD !! ) . But I would not say "hardcode" is always best practice ( even if it IS easier - and I must admit that sometimes (lazy me ) I also do that ..

Comment: @jasonscript, it's not an overly large file to begin with (at the moment, my js file is 2.2KB, but once it's downloaded, it's going to be in the cache so it doesn't need to be re-downloaded on the other page.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Wordpress based site (which I think is irrelevent to this
>   question, but I'm putting it out there in case it impacts the
>   answers).

It is in fact relevant, because then You should use [wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)..

Those function in wordpress will allow you to correctly register the functions , and allow also an easy filtering to WHERE you want the scripts to register , and also provide and easy way to separate Admin side scripts and regular front side ones . This is the correct way to load scripts in wordpress and also filter their appearance .

The enqueue mechanisem will also take care of any dependencies and will ensure your script is loaded only after such dependencies ( jQuery for example )

like so ( ADMIN AREA ):

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'o99_cfsa_admin_load_scripts');

function o99_cfsa_admin_load_scripts($hook){ // notice the HOOK for admin pages

if( $hook != 'widgets.php' ) // this will load only on widgets pages admin 
        return;
// in this example , the chosen_k script will not load before the dependecies (first jquery, then chosen , then custom chosen_k script..)
    wp_enqueue_script('chosen', plugins_url( '/js/chosen.jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'),'099',TRUE); 
    wp_enqueue_script('chosen_k', plugins_url( '/js/k99.chosen.init.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery','chosen'),'099',TRUE); 
    wp_enqueue_style('chosencss', plugins_url( '/js/chosen.css', __FILE__ ), array(),'all'); 

}
```

That example is for the admin side , but to use it on the front side , you just need to use a different action :

```
        add_action('enqueue_scripts', 'o99_cfsa_load_scripts'); // Different action

    function o99_cfsa_load_scripts(){ 

    if( is_front_page() ) // example : this will load on all EXCEPT front page 
            return;
    // in this example , the chosen_k script will not load before the dependecies (first jquery, then chosen , then custom chosen_k script..)
        wp_enqueue_script('chosen', plugins_url( '/js/chosen.jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'),'099',TRUE); 
        wp_enqueue_script('chosen_k', plugins_url( '/js/k99.chosen.init.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery','chosen'),'099',TRUE); 
        wp_enqueue_style('chosencss', plugins_url( '/js/chosen.css', __FILE__ ), array(),'all');
}
```

This will allow you to easily control the pages also on the front-end with simple [wp conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) :

```
 if ( is_front_page() ) {
wp_enqueue_script('chosen', plugins_url( '/js/chosen.jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'),'099',TRUE);
}
```

or in your case

```
 if ( is_single( array( 17, 19, 1, 11 ) )  ) { // array of your single posts ID´s 
wp_enqueue_script('chosen', plugins_url( '/js/chosen.jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'),'099',TRUE);
}
```

or even

```
is_page( 'my-page' ) // for pages, using slug . see the conditional tags .
```

Note that it is always better to first register, and then enqueue the scripts . ( read the documentation of the functions linked above )

See more info here :

http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html

http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-stylesheets-to-wordpress-correctly

or just search google for "correctly load javascript wordpress "

Another way , much less recommended would be to use the [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) and [`wp_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) actions to directly print your scripts ( but again, not the best practice ):

```
    function your_script_print_function() {
if ( is_single( array( 17, 19, 1, 11 ) )  ){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">

            // <![CDATA[

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                           // your script here ..
                });

            // ]]>

        </script>'; 
}
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'your_script_print_function', 100); // or wp_head
```

Comment: I think this answer has gone off on a tangent, since my original questions wasn't about where to include scripts, is more specific to assuming that jQuery is loaded, and my script is loaded, and what is the best way (if my example code isn't) to incorporate js functionality on specific pages.

Comment: I'm currently using Thesis 2.x Theme/Framework. The framework supports various "skins" and in the skin editor, I can edit existing or create new page templates. Each template has a configuration that let's me choose from a list of popular js libraries that I want to add to my page. It's not pulling them from a CDN. It also has boxes for each page template where I can add header scripts and footer scripts and I added my script file to the footer script box.

I'm sure that Thesis is only loading those scripts on the "front site" and not the admin side.

Comment: @MarkS . well - I do not think this is "off on a tangent" because those `wp_enqueue()` functions actually allow for assuring jQuery is loaded, and assuring your script loads selectively on certain pages . like you said in your comment . secondly - I summed up the correct way to load scripts in wordpress themes, plugins and custom functions . weather you want to use it or not is totally up to you.

Comment: OK, so assuming that I have ensured jQuery is loaded and my scripts are loaded on select pages where they are to be used and I've done all this correctly using `wp_enqueue`, go back to the my original question about the jQuery stuff.

Comment: @MarkS assuming all the above mentioned - your original question is NULLED. But OK - I understand .  you want to do things your way ( the hard hackish way ) . If you want - just say so and I will delete my answer to not disturb you getting the answer you want ( instead of the one you need )

Comment: It's not NULLED because you're answering a question that I never asked. You're fixated on how to properly load a script and how to conditionally load a script.

Comment: Sure, I can take all of your advice, but now that I have the script loaded, only on posts with ID's 17, 19, 1, and 11, or...  Let's say I'm using jQuery on a static site, with HTML edited in notepad and no Wordpress or CMS. Back to my original question: What's considered the best practice for having page specific js from that loaded script run when the page is ready and do the page specific javascript. All of the code is on the single additional .js file, and it could be run as I showed in my OP, or maybe I could register three different functions with three separate calls to ready(), or...

Comment: The best practice in that case is to give each page it´s own ID and add that ID to the `jQuery` selector .But sorry, I am bad at giving "bad practice" advise .. I will just delete my answer .

Comment: I do appreciate that you've said about script loading best practices. So it's not like you've wasted my time in explaining that aspect of Wordpress which I'm happy to learn more about.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .each() ( [info](http://api.jquery.com/each/) ):

```
$('#myhelpform').each(function( index ) {
    // do stuff
});
```

If you want to separate out into functions I think you have to wrap your function call inside the each function, like this:

```
$('#myhelpform').each(function( index ) {
    myhelpform(this);
});
```